# xargs doens't understand subl alias for Sublime Text

Tags: bash, sublimetext, xargs

I'm on windows using GitBash and I have this in my bash profile:

`alias subl='/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe'`

I can open files easily:

```
$ touch foo.txt 
$ subl !$
```

... it works.

However, when using xargs, I can't pipe files into subl as arguments:

```
$ git grep -l "internal interface" | xargs subl
xargs: subl: No such file or directory
```

Other text editors do work:

```
$ git grep -l "internal interface" | xargs code  # VsCode
```

`xargs` also doesn't find the full absolute path:

```
$ git grep -l "internal interface" | xargs '/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe'
xargs: /c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe: No such file or directory
```

*This fails on any drive/volumne on this machine.

Comment: Alias expansion is only attempted for the first word of a command.

Comment: does that mean this should still fail?
`$ git grep -l "internal interface" | xargs '/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe'`

Comment: Can you try dropping the backslashes in your last command? Because the string is single quoted, the backslashes are literal.

Comment: `xargs` doesn't use the shell to run the command, it's the shell that expands aliases.

Comment: @BenjaminW. dropping the slashes in the string command works.

Comment: Instead of aliasing, couldn't you add sublime to your `PATH`? Or, if you don't like `sublime_text.exe`, symlink it to `~/bin/subl` and make sure that `~/bin` is in your `PATH`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. - that sounds like the right move, thanks

Comment: Anecdotally on Windows, `subl.exe` and `sublime_text.exe` are both subtly different. `subl` is a small console app that can communicate with and launch Sublime, which `sublime_text` is the actual application. Results of calling one over the other from the console may differ (though I don't know if that would impact this particular issue).